EF Core 8 - more efficient way to code this? Something like a SQL Case statement?
The code:
var primeCtr = con.Contractors?.Where(ctr => ctr.Type == "Prime").FirstOrDefault();
if (primeCtr == null)
   primeCtr = con.Contractors?.Where(ctr => ctr.Type == "Original Prime").FirstOrDefault();

Explanation:
If a contractor of type "Prime" exists, use that one, else use the "Original Prime"
I could have coded this using ? : expression but I think it would have been less efficient?
var primeCtr = con.Contractors?.Where(ctr => ctr.Type == "Prime").Any() ? con.Contractors?.Where(ctr => ctr.Type == "Prime").FirstOrDefault() : con.Contractors?.Where(ctr => ctr.Type == "Original Prime").FirstOrDefault();

The query for "Prime" would get executed twice I think?
Just trying to determine if there is a more elegant way to express this using EF Core 8?  This is my first EF Core app and I haven't used the old EF in several years, so could be rusty.

I don't believe any of the OrderBy options are going to be efficient, what you have has good performance if awkward, assuming an index on Type

The most common way to to this is ordering by preference and take the first:
con.Contractors.OrderByDescending(ctr => ctr.Type == "Prime").FirstOrDefault()

If there are more types you'll have to filter out "Prime" and "Original Prime" (add a Where before the ordering).
The ordering is descending because then the one where ctr.Type == "Prime" is true floats to the top.

Side note, assuming that con is a context instance, con.Contractors is never null and you don't need the ? operator.

That's an interesting idea. There ARE more types, but they are pre-filtered before this logic. I like this answer, but i am curious what sql impact is.


Just trying to determine if there is a more elegant way to express this using EF Core 8?

Arguably there is no "nice" way to express this in SQL, but there are options if you want to save roundtrips you can do something like the following:
var primeCtr = con.Contractors
    .Where(ctr => new []{"Prime", "Original Prime"}.Contains(ctr.Type))
    .OrderByDescending(ctr => ctr.Type)
    .FirstOrDefault();

Ordering is the key here - it will result in the Prime being on top in case there are any.
To include more types you can use ternary operator:
var primeCtr = con.Contractors
    .Where(ctr => new []{"Prime", "Original Prime", ...}.Contains(ctr.Type))
    .OrderBy(ctr => ctr.Type == "Prime" 
         ? 0
         : ctr.Type == "Original Prime"
             ? 1
             : ....)
    .FirstOrDefault();


In sql a CASE WHEN statement would work well

You can use the ternary operator inside Where/OrderBy:
var primeCtr = con.Contractors.OrderBy(ctr => ctr.Type == "Prime" 
    ? 1 
    : ctr.Type == "Original Prime" ? 2
    : 3).FirstOrDefault();

This translates down into a CASE in SQL: (Don't mind the table/column names, this was just a quick test using a previous table/entity)
SELECT [p].[ProjectId], [p].[Name], [p].[Term1], [p].[Term2], [p].[Term3], [p].[TestDateTime]
FROM [Projects] AS [p]
ORDER BY CASE
    WHEN [p].[Term1] = N'orange' THEN 1
    WHEN [p].[Term1] = N'apple' THEN 2
    ELSE 3
END

You can add as many values as needed and gives full control over the order without assuming either an ascending or descending order on the Type value.

I could have sworn the ternary wouldn't work in that expression.  But that could be me misremembering, or an old EF version.   Great, because this is how I would have done it in SQL.
